# What do I need to know when deploying a new SHA2 HTTPS certificate?

Tags: https

We are using SHA1 for now, and we are required to apply new HTTPS certificate which supports SHA2.

Can I deploy SHA2 certificates directly to production environment? Do I need to test it? What problems will I encounter?

Comment: It is a high quality question with a high quality answer. There is no reason to close it.

Answer (score 6):

SHA-2 (commonly SHA-256) signed certificates should be compatible with most recent systems. Certain older operating systems (Server 2003, XP SP2) and browsers (Chrome 25, Opera 8, IE5) do not support them, but as long as you are running anything from the last decade you should be okay.

DigiCert has a fairly comprehensive guide on SHA-2 compatibility available at their site:

[SHA-2 Compatibility | Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/sha-2-compatibility.htm)

All in all, it's not much of a choice.  CAs will stop issuing SHA-1 signed certificates soon, and most browsers will begin to give errors for SHA-1 signed certificates.